# Nspredicate between

Tags: iphone, arrays, dictionary, nsdate, nspredicate

Can I apply NSPredicate for filter array of dictionary data corresponding to date?

```
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"attributeName BETWEEN %@", @[@1, @10]];
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"attributeName" : @5 };
BOOL between = [betweenPredicate evaluateWithObject:dictionary];
if (between) 
{
    NSLog(@"between");
}
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179128/forming-a-predicate-to-filter-between-dates

Comment: predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date < %@ AND date > %@", maxDate, minDate];     can I apply this predicate direct on array of dictionary.

Comment: `between` clause in NSPredicate is available in OS X 10.5 and later not in IOS, you can [refer here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithFormat:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution to set below format of the predicate for filter myArray by date.

Its really fast when we have huge amount of data in the array.

```
NSArray *filteredarray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate 
predicateWithFormat:@"(EventStartDateForMonthview <=  %@) AND 
(EventEndDateForMonthview >=  %@)", strOndate,strOndate]];
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `EventStartDateForMonthview` and `EventEndDateForMonthview` was a `NSDate` type or `NSString` ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your start and end date ranges, use the predicate as

```
NSDate * startDate,*endDate;


// Your logic to calculate range


NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K <= %@) AND (%K >=  %@)",@"attributeName",startDate,@"attributeName",endDate]];

BOOL isContainObjects = [myArray filterArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]count];
```